# Makefile dependency for included files in multiple subdirectories

Tags: makefile, docbook

I'm working with docbook and would like to use GNU Make for building. In my top level sub-directory, I have two directories `doc` and `html`, and `stylesheet.xsl` in the top level directory. In `doc`, there is a docbook file and a folder with the xincludes for that docbook (e.g. article1.docbook and a directory named article1 containing all the xincludes from article1.docbook). Like this:

```
toplevel
|
|---doc
|    |-article1.docbook
|    |---article1
|    |    |
|    |    |---sect1.docbook
|    |    |---sect2.docbook
|    |
|    |-article2.docbook
|    |---article2
|    etc...
|
|---html
|    |
|    |---article1.html
|    |---article2.html
|
|---stylesheet.xsl
```

I've come up with this makefile. It builds the html as needed, but doesn't know about the dependencies in sub-directories (e.g. sect1.docbook if article1.docbook is being built, even if article1.docbook hasn't been modified):

```
XSL_HTML = stylesheet.xsl
HTML_OUT = html
DOCBOOK = $(wildcard doc/*.docbook)
HTML = $(patsubst doc/%.docbook,%.html,$(DOCBOOK))

all: $(addprefix html/, $(HTML))

html/%.html : doc/%.docbook
    xsltproc --xinclude \
        --stringparam root.filename '' \
        --output $@ $(XSL_HTML) $<
```

So I need to add a dependency like `$(wildcard doc/%/*.docbook)`, which is where I'm stuck.

Comment: Does your version of Make have Secondary Expansion?

Comment: I believe so; I'm using GNU Make from Cygwin.

Comment: The this might work (I have only old version handy, so I can't test): after `.SECONDEXPANSION:`, use `$$(wildcard doc/$$*/*.docbook)`

Comment: That in itself doesn't seem to work, but I don't quite understand secondary expansion so I'll look into it a bit.

Comment: And the link... http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion

Comment: Okay, so ony the top-level `*.docbook` files generate corresponding HTML files, correct? All of the deeper `*.docbook` files are include files? Does it go deeper than one level down?

Comment: If the include dependencies for these nested `.docbook` include files strictly follow the directory hierarchy, then the dependency graph can be computed from the directory hierarchy itself. If there is only one level of depth then this is as simple as iterating over the root `.docbook` files. For each one, iterate over the children, and add them as dependencies. You can use GNU Make's `eval` to install computed dependencies (as an alternative to spitting out a dependency makefile which is `include`-d.)

Comment: @Kaz You are correct; it does not go down any deeper. This collection is a series of articles, with `articlename.docbook` and `articlename` (a directory) that contains all the xincludes.